E (475768) MQTT_CLIENT: mqtt_message_receive: transport_read() error: errno=128
I am facing some issues while connecting ESP32 to HIVEMQTT broker.
I have attached the output it gives below:
This image contains the output from the device.
These are the credentials I have used in the device:
esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_cfg = {
       // .host = "mqtt://broker.hivemq.com",
        .uri = "mqtt://b9f******************************.s2.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883",
        .port = 8883,
        .username = "e**************5",
        .password = "e********",
        .client_id = "Ta******",
       // .event_handle = "mqtt_event_handler",
        .disable_auto_reconnect = false,
        .lwt_qos = 0,
        //.transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_TCP,       //choosing TCP over TLS/SSL
    };

    esp_mqtt_client_handle_t client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_cfg);
    esp_mqtt_client_register_event(client, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, mqtt_event_handler, client);
    esp_mqtt_client_start(client);

    vTaskDelay(1000);

I am expecting it to connect to the broker, subscribe to create topic then publish a value in it and then subscribe again to fetch the value.
